# Get user \n to be a newline in the string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, byte, backslash

I am making an asymmetrical cryptography system.

I want to be able to paste the encrypted message into the python script and then unencrypt it.

Here's the problem.

The encrypted message contains escape characters and is in bytes.

```
Encrypted message: b'\xa0\xcc&g\x82\x86\xb6\x18\x8bm\xd1\xa2\xa9?\x97xp\xcd\xb2P\x06u\x07a\x169x\xe8\x9f~\x891\x98H\x80\x15\xcdq\xa9\xba\xe0\x07\x0c\x9b\xc9\xe8\xd6\xa80+o\x02c\x98\x1ct%R\xdf})\xe2\xa3\xad\x8a\x9aZ\xd1\xb0\xbfe\x85\xf3\x1a1 \xad\xeb+3Pa\xder\x8ex?\xf7+\xf14 \xa0\xff\x05\x93\xc4\x1c(\x99\x9e\xa3VS\xd2\xa2\xa7\xae/Q\'\xde\xa3\xad\xe3\xb4!\xa1\x8a\xc1\x10\xe7\xf0\xbd2\xd0\x0f5\xa4@\xca,^(\x16N\x16E\xb9\x85\xd7\xf4\x89\t\x8c\x8b\x1a\x9d*\x97\xe5\xf6\xae\x93\x81(\x9b\x94\tq\x01\x04f@W\x14\x97=\x89-v\xf6\\\x15\x97\xe2S\x93}\xf4\x97\x83@d\x08KT\\"n+\x1d\xa2I\xea\x00/\x1d\xc3\x0c\xa5\xb7D\x1d\xff\xfa\x99\x9b\x13\xf0\x9b8/\r\xe2\xc6\xcdHM\x9e\x9e5+\xc9)1\xc8\x01\xf5by\xa6\xf4\xff\x9e[\x9cL\x14\xe7\xaa;\xc8Y\xe53\xcb\xd0.\xd5\xcf\xed\x1d\xd0\xff\xd1'
```

So, if i get the user input and convert it into a byte string, this will happen.

```
# assume user input is \xa0
user_input = input()
print(user_input.encode())

# Prints out \\xa0
```

This treats the `\` as a literal, but I want it to treat it as in escape character.

Or to put it simply, how can I take `"hello\nworld"` from the user using the `input` method and print out

```
hello
world
```

instead of `hello\nworld`

This is what I have tried

```py
print(input_str.encode())
# I get b'hello\\nworld'

decoded_str = input_str.encode().decode('unicode_escape')
print(decoded_str)
# I get 'hello\nworld'

decoded_str = input_str.encode().decode('unicode_escape').encode()
print(decoded_str)
# I get b'hello\nworld'
```

Comment: "decoded_str = input_str.encode().decode('unicode_escape')" - this one works for me, and is the expected way to solve the problem, as explained in the linked duplicate. I can't reproduce the supposed issue with it. Make sure the test input actually contains a backslash, and make sure that you understand what the test output actually contains.